# Are ArcGIS Pro Pop-ups same as ArcMap HTML Popups?

Tags: arcgis-pro, popup, html-popup

I am trying to come up to speed on ArcGIS Pro Pop-ups and a piece of information that eludes me is whether reading any ArcMap documentation on HTML Popups is likely to be helpful or confusing.

Can ArcGIS Pro Pop-ups be considered to work the same way as ArcMap HTML Popups or should I forget what I have learned or read about ArcMap HTML Popups and focus solely on ArcGIS Pro Pop-ups documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should focus on the ArcGIS Pro documentation, since they don't work the same way as the HTML popups. The two software are totally different. HTML can only be used for configuring the ArcMap or ArcGIS Online pop ups.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/pop-ups.htm